# Gulp-replace not working latest version

Tags: gulp, gulp-replace

```html
// Create a scss theme file
gulp.task('theme-scss', function() {

  return gulp.src(['./retailer-theme.json']).on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(replace('/.*/m', 'hello')).on('error', gutil.log)
    //.pipe(jsonSass({prefix: '$theme: '})).on('error', gutil.log)
    /*.pipe(rename({
      dirname: './',
      basename: 'retailer',
      suffix: '-theme',
      extname: '.scss'
    })).on('error', gutil.log)*/
    .pipe(gulp.dest(APP_DIR + '/scss/variables/')).on('error', gutil.log)
})
```

Trying the replace everything in the file with the word hello.`enter code here`
The text in retailer-theme.json is text

```
.pipe(replace('text', 'hello')).on('error', gutil.log)
```

The above line works as expected

Answer (score 1):

```
.pipe(replace(new RegExp('.*'), 'hello')).on('error', gutil.log)
```

So I had to create a regexp object, would of been nice if they had this in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you just removed the quotes from your original regexp

```
.pipe(replace('/.*/m', 'hello')).on('error', gutil.log)
```

to

```
.pipe(replace(/.*/m, 'hello')).on('error', gutil.log)
```

I bet it works.  With the quotes it just found no match.

Comment: You are right about the not quote marks it works, only thing is I had to replace the m flag with the g flag, using a regex object does work too, thanks